# Asymptotic behaviour of a function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, asymptotics

Suppose I have a  function $u_0:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R^+$ with compact support contained in the interval $[0,1]$ and such that $\int_0^1u_0(r)dr=1$.

I would like to analyze the function $$v(t,r)=u_0((r-r_0)e^t+r_0)e^t$$ where $r_0=\int_0^1ru_0(r)dr$.

I can prove that $\int_0^1v(t, r)dr=1$ and that since $u_0$ has compact support the function $v(t,r)$ is different from $0$ only in an interval which becomes smaller and smaller as the time increases and this allows to conclude that, as $t\to +\infty$,
$$\int_0^1v(t,r)G(r)dr\rightarrow G(r_0)$$,
for every test function $G$.

What can I say about the $$\lim_{t\to +\infty}v(t,r)$$

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The limit depends on the function $u_0$.

Denote the support of $u_0$ as $A$. If $r_0=\int_0^1ru_0(r)\,dr\in A^。$, for example, $u_0(r)=1$ on $[0,1]$ and $=0$ in other places, then 
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow+\infty}v(t,r)=\left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
0& r\neq r_0,\\
+\infty&r=r_0\\
\end{array}\right.$$
if $u_0(r_0)>0$, since when $r\neq r_0$, for sufficiently large $t$, $(r-r_0)e^t+r_0\notin[0,1]$ and thus $v(t,r)=0$.

If $u_0(r_0)=0$, for example, 
$$u_0(r)=\left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
2&r\in[0,\frac14]\cup[\frac34,1],\\
0&\text{otherwise}\\
\end{array}\right.$$
where $r_0=\frac12$ and thus $u_0(r_0)=0$. In this case, $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow+\infty}v(t,r)=0$.

Comment: Sorry, in your second example is not true that $\lim_t\to\infty \int_0^1v(t, r)G(r)dr=G(r_0)$?

Comment: it  is also not true that $\int_0^1v(t, r)dr=1$. Am I wrong?

Comment: @user268193 So how did you prove these two identities in your problem settings? As you can see, my second example satisfies your assumptions that $u_0$ has compact support contained in $[0,1]$ and $\int u_0=1$. Are these two identities(you mentioned in the comments) your assumptions?

Comment: About the limit I am not sure but the fact that $\int_0^1v(t, r)=1$ is a consequence of a change of variables in the integral and on the fact that $u_0$ has compact support. Am I wrong?

Comment: @user268193 Note that for any fixed $t$, the support of $v(t,r)$ may not be contained in $r\in[0,1]$. So $\int_\mathbb Rv(t,r)\,dr=1$ but $\int_0^1v(t,r)\,dr$ may not equal 1